# Retrieving Hierarchal data in Entity Code-First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, code-first

I have some hierarchal data.  The Model class I use looks like this:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryID")]
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ListOrder { get; set; }


    // left/right
    public int TreeLeft { get; set; }
    public int TreeRight { get; set; }
}   // eo class Category
```

I've used the techniques outlined [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) to store my data, and inserting and retrieving data is not a problem.

What I would like to do, is add a Category collection to this class:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Category> {get; set; }
```

I've used this technique in the past (learned from the Mvc tutorials), to include related tables when getting data.  However, when I tried this I received an error with regard to IEnumerable<> being abstract (which is understandable, I guess the framework couldn't figure out what I want to do)...

... and indeed, being new to LINQ, I have no idea what the LINQ would look like that would give me back a collection of `Category` instances each of which had their children inside them.

If it's not possible I guess I can construct the list manually, use a regular LINQ query to get all the categories at a particular position (and their children) and manually populate it all.

I was wondering if LINQ could do this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to use inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a self reference fk than the collection should be generated automatically when you add the table to the dbml file

And will look something like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Category_Category", Storage="Categories", ThisKey="pkCategoryID", OtherKey="ParentCategoryID")]
public EntitySet<Category> Categories
{
  get
  {
    return this._Categories;
  }
  set
  {
    this._Categories.Assign(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: But, as the child categories have children etc, would this not require some kind of recursive LINQ?  I can't see how to do it without manually populating them myself.

Comment: It will only give you the children at depth one. If you want to get the childrens children also I suggest you write a recursive function in memory as there is no linq2sql that can do that.

Comment: so is the best thing to do to add a concrete List<Category> property to the Category class and manually populate it?  I'm fine with doing that, I can just retrieve the whole tree (in order, no recursion required) and populate them myself.

Comment: You can do something like that, if you can do it without recursion even better.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `IEnumerable<Category>` but `Collection<Category>` . If that is your problem..